# Wireless connectivity problem

Tags: wireless, networking

im a new ubuntu user. I have decided to dual boot ubuntu and windows because i wanted to give ubuntu a try and maybe make it as my primary os. But im currently having problems with my wireless network because it only displays 2 bars and that its very slow (especially loading 2 or more tabs) compared to my windows, which doesn't have a problem with the wireless conection. Need help on this please thanks! :)

PS. Im really liking ubuntu so far, just having this bit of a problem.

Edit. I have ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I would not do random things without even knowing what driver is being used, those recommendation in the link are for certain drivers, as is the command below. Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I will post the diagnosis as soon as I get home, thank you for helping!

Comment: --2014-06-25 22:30:20--  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script
Resolving dl.dropbox.com (dl.dropbox.com)... failed: Connection timed out.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘dl.dropbox.com’
-This is what i get...what does it mean?

Comment: Looks like you did not have an internet connection when you ran the script.

Comment: Ok so i used my cellphone and used its mobile data and usb to tether to my phone and it works magnificently, so this is what i got from the txt file.
http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7705625/

Answer (score 0):

[itsfoss.com](http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/) has some tips which helped speedup my wireless - I would ignore the part about WICD, as it does not seem to be supported currently, and does not totally integrate into Ubuntu 14.04.

A second post which also helped advised entering the following command into a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that. One question though do I just copy  paste the second post on the terminal? Sorry for the stupid question just wanted to be sure lol

Comment: No problem.  Yes, the second item is intended to be posted directly into a terminal - the sudo command executes the remainder of the command as root.  Of the 4 packages being installed, the last one is the important one.  The others are not bad to have, but probably not essential.

Comment: @ordnaela  I forgot to tell you that you should reboot after the package installs...

Comment: Last question, will the first link you gave me work on ubuntu 14.04? Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Yes, they work pretty well.  I've also just installed libnss-myhostname, which strangely also seems to be helping.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your help! I'll try to make the changes as soon as I get home and hopefully it will work haha.

Comment: Hello Charles Green, this is what i got after i pasted it on the terminal..what does this mean? lol
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
E: Unable to locate package linux-firmware-nonfree

Comment: You need to check your software sources (available in System Settings) - on the first tab, allow proprietary drivers should be checked - I get everything but source code, on the second tab check cannonical partners.  Then you will need to run sudo apt-get update

Comment: Ok i copy and pasted the thing to the terminal and it updated and all that stuff but sadly it didnt work wireless still useless :(

Comment: OK - last thing to try - it's really bare bones, but it worked on my wifes HP Pavilion - how far from the wireless router are you?  My wife's computer would become very intermittent at about 60 feet.

Comment: Im currently sleeping in my sisters room at the 3rd floor and i usually sleep on the 2nd floor where the router is :)

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
sudo modprobe -v ath9k
```

In your router change encryption to just wpa2 (CCMP)(AES) not (TKIP) if you have that option (TKIP) is known to slow the connection down.

Also you have two connections with the same name and are on the same channel, you need to remove the weakest one.

In network manager change your settings to match the screenshots.
[image: DNS SERVER] [image: IPV6]

Make sure your ethernet connection and tethering is disconnected by unplugging the phone and ethernet cable, then reboot the computer before testing your connection speed.

Also remember distance and what the walls and floors are made of if you have more then one floor between the computer and router affect the signal and speed.